# php function parameters

Tags: php

How to write a php function in order to pass parameters 
like this

student('name=Nick&roll=1234');

Comment: Why would you do something like that?

Answer (score 3):

If your format is URL encoded you can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the variables in your functions scope:

```
function student($args)
{
    parse_str($args);
    echo $name;
    echo $roll;
}
```

Although, if this string is the scripts URL parameters you can just use the [$_GET global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Answer (score 2):

Pass parameters like this:

```
student($parameter1, $parameter2){
//do stuff
return $something;
}
```

call function like this:

```
student($_GET['name'], $_GET['roll']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo($paraString){

    try{
    $expressions = explode('&',$paraString);
    $args = array();
    foreach($expressions as $exoression){
      $kvPair =  explode('=',$exoression);
      if(count($kvPair !=2))throw new Exception("format exception....");
      $args[$kvPair[0]] = $kvPair[1];
    }
    ....
```

Edit: that wayyou can do it manually. If you just want to get something out of a querrystring there are already functions to get the job done